# Getting whole iframe with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to scrape an iframe from a website, but cannot seem to scrape the whole iframe (not just attributes) (for post purpose I'll do a basic iframe)

```
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

The content on each iframe is prone to change, so need to regex the iframe tags some how, I have tried with the following buy can't get it to work:

```
<iframe[^>]*>(.*?)</iframe[^>]*>"
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be because your iframe is spanning multiple lines. In that case, you should know that `.` doesn't match newline character, so you can replace it with `(?:.|\n)` or `[^<]` or use the dot-all/single line flag so that dot matches all characters. Also you might want to use this regex instead: [`<iframe[^>]*?(?:\/>|>[^<]*?<\/iframe>)`](https://regex101.com/r/LIFaXi/3) which also matches `<iframe />`

Comment: minor mistake in your regex: the second alternative in the unnamed group needs to start with `>` so you grab the final character of the opening tag. Also, all RegEx-parsing-HTML stuff is prone to blow up in case of nested tags (eg. input "<iframe><iframe>bleh</iframe>bleh</iframe>")